# C program to call pam_passwdqc.so and report password strength, pass/fail

Tags: c, passwords, pam

Is it possible (and where would I find the interface documentation) to write a simple C program to use pam_passwdqc.so to determine if a potential password will be strong enough to pass muster under passwd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually want is [libpasswdqc](http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/), which is the stand alone version of the PAM module. The source / download links are at the middle of the page(note, if you just want the checking functionality, you probably just want the library).

The file INTERNALS points you to the header, which is brief and self explanatory. The file `pwqcheck.c` illustrates pretty much what you want to accomplish.

At least on my Ubuntu workstation, I could not find a package that didn't also install all of the PAM bits. The stand alone library is small enough to drop into almost any tree, if the dependency would be problematic for you.

Then again, you could try linking to the DSO, The interface might be the same. The way my OS packages it, it's kind of hard to tell. The library uses the most permissive version of the BSD license that I've ever seen, so dropping it in place is a non-issue:

> Redistribution and use in source and
>   binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted.
>
> THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE
>   AUTHOR AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
>   ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES,
>   INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
>   IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY
>   AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
>   ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHOR OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR
>   ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
>   SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
>   DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
>   SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
>   PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
>   HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
>   LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
>   NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
>   ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
>   SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
>   POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Answer (score 2):

Pam is using [cracklib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cracklib/) for password checking, you should check it also.

Comment: Cracklib's interface couldn't get any easeir .. two whopping functions :) Plus there's something hilarious about passing `-lcrack`.

Comment: There, a +1 to go with my comment now that I finally have votes back :)